# split each element of array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, split

I have a problem.

I have the following input string :

```
String text = "John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
```

I have developed the below code :

```
public Person(String warehouse) {
    // Separating people
    String[] peopleArray = warehouse.split(" ");
    
    System.out.println(peopleArray[0]);  //John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade
    System.out.println(peopleArray[1]);  //Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov
    System.out.println(peopleArray[2]);  //Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow
    
    
    
    String[] person1 = peopleArray[0].split("/|\\."); 
    
    System.out.println(person1[0]);  //John

    
    
}
```

I want to split each element of `peopleArray` with the `< .split("/|\\.") >` and put every person in a new array

The exact request :
In the main class, after creating the Person object and filling in its fields, the Person object must be put in the collection (for example, in the list) and at the end a passage must be made through this collection and the data about people must be written.

I think it should look like this:

```
John, Davidson, 05082004, Belgrad
Michael, Barton, 01011998, Krakov,
Ivan, Perkinson, 23051986, Moscow
```

Comment: You can loop through the ```person1``` array and create a new array for each person in that array. However this is probably terribly inefficient. Why exactly do you need to create a new array for each person?

Comment: I don't understand. Is your code doing this? Or is it not doing it? Do you only need the first name of all the entries? What is your desired end result?

Comment: This was the request. Did i get it wrong?
in the main class, after creating the Person object and filling in its fields, the Person object must be put in the collection (for example, in the list) and at the end a passage must be made through this collection and the data about people must be written.

Comment: @DannyB Can you explain with an example in your Question? Do you mean to say you want, in this case, three person objects in a list? Or three arrays like person1 in a list? I'm not sure if you only want the first name or all the data of each strings (from "John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade")?

Comment: @Scratte i want all the data of each string. it should look something like this, in the end: 
John Davidson 05. avg 2004. Belgrade

Michael Barton 01. jan 1998. Krakov

Ivan Perkinson 23. maj 1986. Moscow

Answer (score 1):

I think he needs arrays to manipulate them in another moment and not only strings representation of the array. Well, you can build a List of arrays and then get the array you want with data from there:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
          // Separating people
   String warehouse = "John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";

    List<String[]> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] peopleArray = warehouse.split(" ");

    for (String s : peopleArray){
          String[] person1 = s.split("/|\\."); 
          nameList.add(person1);
    }
   
   nameList.forEach(x -> {
       System.out.println(x[0]);
       }); //print only names of ALL the people
       
   System.out.println("\ALL info about the first person and so on... :");

    String[] person = nameList.get(0);
    for (String s: person){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
 }
```

**Output**

```
John
Michael
Ivan

All info about the first person and so on... :
John
Davidson
05082004
Belgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
String[] person1 = peopleArray[0].split("[\\./]");
```

You may try use some regex tester e.g. https://regex101.com/. But remember to escape some chars e.g. backslash to double backslash

Another thing is:
The peopleArray[0], peopleArray[1], peopleArray[2] actually can be solved using loop e.g. for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `peopleArray` and keep the data for each person in a 2D array

```
String[] peopleArray = text.split(" ");
String[][] peopleDetailsArray = new String[peopleArray.length][4];
for (int i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++) {
  peopleDetailsArray[i] = peopleArray[i].split("/|\\.");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(peopleDetailsArray));
```

Output:

```
[[John, Davidson, 05082004, Belgrade], [Michael, Barton, 01011998, Krakov], [Ivan, Perkinson, 23051986, Moscow]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String text = "John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
        
        String[] peopleArray = text.split(" ");
        String[][] personArray = new String[peopleArray.length][4];
        for(int i=0; i<peopleArray.length; i++){
            personArray[i] = peopleArray[i].split("/|\\.");
            for(int j=0; j<personArray[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(personArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
John Davidson 05082004 Belgrade                                                                                                                             
Michael Barton 01011998 Krakov                                                                                                                              
Ivan Perkinson 23051986 Moscow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Java 8 map to get 2D array of Person as -

```
String text = "John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";

String[][] strings = Arrays.stream(text.split(" ")).
                     map(str -> str.split("/|\\.")).toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(strings));
```

Output -

```
[[John, Davidson, 05082004, Belgrade], [Michael, Barton, 01011998, Krakov], [Ivan, Perkinson, 23051986, Moscow]]
```